# My Lexus sedan has a water leak

Tags: lexus

We have checked sunroof and wiper drains and both are clear.  But water continues to come in and soak carport.

Comment: What is *model* and *year* of your Lexus?

Comment: 2006.  Sedan 360 I think.  4 door

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain the drain for the HVAC housing isn't clogged.  Do you hear sloshing noises when making sharp turns or lane changes?

Does this happen all the time, or only after a rain?  If it's rain-related, check around  the windshield for rust or gasket failure, and make certain the side window welting has no gaps.

Also, the sunroof drains might be clear, but also make sure they have not gotten disconnected or split where they join the gutter channel.